# angular ui-router all controllers get reloaded with state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having an issue with angular ui-router where all controllers on a given state are being refreshed when going to the same state (but with different params).  For reference my states are like:

**Main States**

```
{
    'app': {
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'AppCtrl',
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    },
    'app.clients': {
        url: '/clients/:id',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'stage.html', //has named list and detail views
                controller: 'ClientsCtrl'
            },
            'list@app.clients': {
                templateUrl: 'client-list.html',
                controller: 'ClientListCtrl'
            },
            'detail@app.clients': {
                templateUrl: 'client-profile.html',
                controller: 'ClientProfileCtrl'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So initially this all seems to work well.  `client-list.html` looks like:

**client-list.html**

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat='client in clients'>
        <a ui-sref='pencilem.clients({id: client.id})'>{{client.fullName}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, the desired behavior is that when a client is clicked on in the client list, their profile is rendered, the url is updated (with the new client id), but I don't want to re-initialize all the controllers that don't need the update.  This causes issues with scrolled views (that re-render to the top of the view) and is costly if there are operations happening in those controllers that slow stuff down.  The image below highlights the issue, as soon as a client is clicked on, that view (pink, ClientListCtrl) has it's controller called again, and a re-render is triggered, scrolling to the top of that div)

Is there any way using multiple views / controllers to avoid this? I could pass around an "activeClient" object in services which should propegate to the various controllers, but then I loose pastable urls to navigate to a state.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the stuff you don't want to update to an abstract parent state, roughly like this:

```
{
    'app': {
        abstract: true,
        controller: 'AppCtrl',
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    },     
    'app.clients': {
        url: '/clients',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'stage.html', //has named list and detail views
                controller: 'ClientsCtrl'
            },
            'list@app.clients': {
                templateUrl: 'client-list.html',
                controller: 'ClientListCtrl'
            }
        }
    },
    'app.clients.detail': {
        url: '/:id',
        views: {
            'detail@app.clients': {
                templateUrl: 'client-profile.html',
                controller: 'ClientProfileCtrl'
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: This looks to do what I want it to.  I'm gonna do some testing / rearchitecting my app tonight and will accept this as the answer shortly.  Thanks @Rytmis!

Comment: It took a bit more engineering of my controllers, but this is indeed what I was looking for.  I can now change to a specific profile state without the abstract views re-rendering.  Thanks!

Comment: The key is to have the views and controllers you wish to keep in a parent state -- it doesn't matter if the state is abstract or not.

Comment: That totally makes sense.  Thanks so much @Rytmis!